# About dual and quotients

Tags: functional-analysis

I need help with this exercise, which is supposed to be related with Hahn Banach theorem. It states the following:

If $M$ is a closed subspace of a normed space $X$, and defining $M_0=\lbrace{\psi\in X^{*}: \psi|_M=0\rbrace}$,

-There is an isometric isomorphism between the spaces $(X/M)^{*}$ and  $M_0$.

-And there is also an isometric isomorphism between $(X^{*}/M_0)$ and $M^{*}$.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See theorem 4.9 in Rudin's Functional analysis.

Or see theorem 7 [here](https://noncommutativeanalysis.wordpress.com/2012/11/07/advanced-analysis-notes-7-banach-spaces-dual-spaces-and-duality-lp-spaces-the-double-dual-quotient-spaces/).